# How does Choreographer work

Tags: android, android-framework

I was just studying about code of Android framework (v4.1).

I know that the UI message triggered by `invalidate()` now is posted to Choreographer instead of UI messageQueue directly, and these messages will not be executed until next **VSYNC** signal comes.

Before this post operation is performed, `ViewRootImpl` calls Looper's `postSyncBarrier()` once in order to block the UI MessageQueue which means messages that post into messagesQueue later won't be executed until this block is removed, which happens before function `performTraversals()`.

Based on the above understanding,

> If another **`invalidate()`** is called even once somewhere within **`performTraversals()`** (such as **`onDraw()`** of any view instances) the UI messageQueue forever be blocked?

From practical observations, I know that this never happens.
So, where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the answer to this question by looking at the code for `scheduleTraversals`:

```
void scheduleTraversals() {
    if (!mTraversalScheduled) {
        mTraversalScheduled = true;
        mTraversalBarrier = mHandler.getLooper().postSyncBarrier();
        mChoreographer.postCallback(
                Choreographer.CALLBACK_TRAVERSAL, mTraversalRunnable, null);
        if (!mUnbufferedInputDispatch) {
            scheduleConsumeBatchedInput();
        }
        notifyRendererOfFramePending();
    }
}
```

After the first call to `scheduleTraversals` `mTraversalScheduled` is set true.  Subsequent calls have no affect, `postSyncBarrier` is not be called and no second barrier is put on the queue, until `unscheduleTraversals` is called.